# Tomcat doesn't recognize context file in Linux

Tags: java, tomcat, debian, tomcat9

On my dev machine (running `Windows 10`) I'm using `Tomcat 9` to develop and test a web app. 
Since the app needs a connection string that I don't want to include in the app's WAR package, I've put it in a context XML file and saved that file to `tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/<war_name>.xml`, as suggested in the [official documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context). This works perfectly under Windows.

Now I'm trying to deploy to a production machine, which is running `Linux Debian 10`. I've installed the same version of Tomcat and put the context file in the same location, but this time it's not working: the context file is not recognized and the app fails to start because it doesn't find the required connection string. To make it work, I had to put the context file in `/tomcat/webapps/<war_name>/WEB-INF/context.xml`. This works, but it's very annoying because in that location it gets deleted every time the app is redeployed, so every time I redeploy I have to copy it over.

Is there a reason why this is working on Windows and not on Linux? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... after further testing, turns out that it IS reading the context file, but for some reason it doesn't straight away. I have to wait a couple of minutes and the start the webapp manually from the manager console... strange

Comment: I waited forever and never picks up the domain name from the context file